# create a filter on multiple columns using a single dropdown list. ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKExk.png)i have a situation, i have a  multi select drop down list. I would like to create a filter on multiple columns using a single dropdown list. eg :- Column A or Column B ( Search on column A value or Column B Value) how can i do it ?
REPLY

In the picture release is a multi select drop down list. and i want to filter on Future release as well as release columns that i display the data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKExk.png)

Comment: Can you explain with the help of some example or diagram?

Comment: Do you want to change the visibility of the column or row based on the parameter value or do you want to filter the dataset?

Comment: What database, what have you tried so far, what does your query look like now? REPLY

Comment: i am using sql server 2014. I am unable to upload image, but there is a link. simple question is i have mulit select drop down list and i have two fields , release and future release columns on the report. i want to filter on both the columns like (or) condition if the selected value is in either of the columns display on the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter those two column at dataset level.
In query use "Where Release in (@ReleaseParamater) OR FutureRelease In (@ReleaseParamater)"

While passing parameter to dataset use join function to get value with comma separated like below.
JOIN(Parameters!ReleaseParamater.Value,",")
Check out below image
[Filter Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkCKY.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOQ0L.jpg)

Comment: the whole issue is i can not pass it as a parameter to the sql query. That is why i am trying to filter on the result dataset. My sql query is a union of two data sets and i can not pass the release as parameters.

Comment: Write a Select Statement on top of both the queries and then put where clause. SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM (SELECT * FROM TAB1 UNION SELECT * FROM TAB2) WHERE Release in (@Parameter)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the response, i have made the changes, but the result output is not coming because of the comma separated values. I have given the same expression. =JOIN(Parameters!ReleaseNumber.Value,",") . In the stored procedure it is not taking as comma seperated value like where a.release In ('2.95.0','2.94.3') or a.Feature_Release IN ('2.95.0','2.94.3') but instead it is taking ('2.95.0,2.94.3'). so i think it is not getting the output. i tested that is why i am letting you know. –

Comment: Hey, use some conversion function to correct the parameters.